# Fetching task status with AsyncResult showing SUCCESS immediately after the task is receieved by the celery worker

Tags: python, flask, celery, iasyncresult

I have a code where I am fetching the current status of a celery task by using AsyncResult object. But the problem is the status is SUCCESS immediately after the task is received by the worker even if the task is not yet executed.
Why this is happening and how do I get the right status of the task ?

In my scenario just want to right a script to monitor the task status in some regular interval of time and for that I need the status of the task whether it failed, pending or is completed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.